# Can we get same sex fiance visa even if we only met once?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, germany

I have a boyfriend who is from germany but he is currently working in UK...  We've been together for almost 6months and he wanted me to go with him in UK.. We wanted to get married in the future..  Specifically in UK since here in the philippines same sex marriage is not legalize and recognize.. Is it possible to get fiance visa even if we only met once? I hope someone will give as Idea on what should we do...  Thank you so much

Comment: Having atleast met once is a minimum requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There are two visa options, depending on whether you intend to live in the UK after your marriage. A Marriage Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa permits entry for up to 6 months; a Family visa https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa allows you to settle in the UK. Both require you to prove that the relationship is genuine, it will be nigh on impossible for you to do that if you've only met once.

Comment: Since after being married OP will be eligible for an EEA family permit, the family visa seems definitely *not* the way to go as it is far too costly.  The marriage visa might work, but OP might not be a genuine visitor and therefore might not qualify.  The easiest solution might be to marry somewhere else and then apply for the EEA family permit.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are married, you could qualify for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit), which is free of charge.  It might be easiest to get married in some other jurisdiction.  This might be Germany, since your boyfriend is German, or any that allows nonresidents to marry (I know that New York does, and Las Vegas is famous for this as well).

But hurry!  The UK is on the verge of leaving the European Union, after which this route will almost certainly no longer be possible.

Comment: This may have changed, but Germany had the requirement that a marriage was legal according to German law, and according to the law of both partners. If one partner is from a country where same sex marriage is not allowed, that might stop you from getting married in Germany.